# How to use apache httpd as front for other web servers?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

### What I am trying to do

I want to run Apache httpd (2.4.x) as a front-end for an Apache tomcat (9.0.x) and an Elasticsearch server.

For instance, the user should see

`http://localhost/tomcat/`

which internally is forwarded to

`http://localhost:8080/`

So for example

`http://localhost/tomcat/manager/status`   (externally served by httpd)

is retrieved from

`http://localhost:8080/manager/status`     (internerally coming from Tomcat)

### What I did

mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_rewrite are activated.

In httpd.conf I added

```
ProxyPass /tomcat http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://localhost:8080
```

or alternatively

```
<Location "/tomcat">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

### What is not working

`http://localhost/tomcat/` serves the expected page correctly. However, links on that page are not adjusted to the new base URL.

For instance, the page contains
`<a href="/docs/">Documentation</a>`

Clicking on that link goes to
should go to `http://localhost/tomcat/docs`
but points to `http://localhost/docs`

Please note that, if possible, I would like to use a solution on the Apache httpd side (rather than reconfiguring Tomcat) since later I would like to use the same mechanisms for an Elasticsearch backend.

#### Another small issue

When omitting the trailing slash
`http://localhost/tomcat`
the forwarding works for the HTML page itself, but fails for the embedded resources, e.g., the Tomcat logo should be retrieved as
`http://localhost/tomcat/tomcat.svg` -> `http://localhost:8080/tomcat.svg`
but instead points to
`http://localhost/tomcat.svg` which is not translated, since it no longer matches the Location pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> However, links on that page are not adjusted to the new base URL.

This is the main problem in your configuration: web applications usually generate absolute URI paths like `/manager/images/tomcat.svg` instead of relative URI paths like `images/tomcat.svg`. They retrieve the path at which they are deployed (`/manager`) using [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath--). They have no way of knowing they are being proxied from another path.

That is the reason why the original and proxied URL of web application should keep the same URI paths. In your case you should deploy Tomcat Manager at `/tomcat/manager`. This can be done manifold:

- if your Tomcat Manager application is inside the `<Host>`'s *application base* (`$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`), rename the directory to `tomcat#manager` (this usually happens on Windows),
- if your Tomcat's Manager application is outside of the `<Host>`'s *application base*, rename the context file (in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/<host_name>`) from `manager.xml` to `tomcat#manager.xml` (this happens in Linux distributions like Debian),
- if you define the application context in `server.xml` (not recommended), you can use the [`path`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute of the `<Context>` element.

The number sign `#` will be converted to `/`.

On Apache's side change the `ProxyPass` directive to:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat http://localhost:8080/tomcat
```